# Invalid json in Django-mptt model

Tags: python, json, django

I am writing a custom test case for Django-Mptt template tag . Eveything is working fine but the json I am getting is not valid .

**this is the template string I am sending :**

```
self.template = re.sub(r'(?m)^[\s]+', '', '''
                            {% load yctags %}   
                             [
                                {% recursetree_custom comments comment_order %}
                                {
                                    "comment_id": "{{ node.id }}",
                                    "comment_text": "{{ node.text }}",
                                    "comment_parent_id": "{{ node.parent.id }}",
                                    "children": [
                                    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                                            {{ children }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    ]
                                }
                                {% endrecursetree %}
                            ]''')
```

**output :**

```
[{"comment_id": "2","comment_text": "2nd comment","comment_parent_id": "","children": [{"comment_id": "7","comment_text": "2nd comment , 2nd child","comment_parent_id": "2","children": []}{"comment_id": "6","comment_text": "2nd comment , ist child","comment_parent_id": "2","children": []}]}{"comment_id": "1","comment_text": "Ist comment","comment_parent_id": "","children": [{"comment_id": "3","comment_text": "Ist comment , ist child","comment_parent_id": "1","children": [{"comment_id": "5","comment_text": "1-1-2","comment_parent_id": "3","children": []}{"comment_id": "4","comment_text": "1-1-1","comment_parent_id": "3","children": []}]}]}]
```

If u use any json validator for above o/p then u will know about my error in json output , there must be a comma b/w to comments to make it valid.

Please let me know the solution how I can make this json valid

Comment: Well, you could just add the comma before the `{% endrecursetree %}` tag, but then you'd have a trailing comma, which is invalid too. if it was a `{% for %}` loop you could have used the `forloop.last` variable but since we don't have any doc on your `recursetree_custom` tag there's no obvious solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is join comments by comma ','

```
def _render_node(self, context, node):
        # print "node-> ",node
        bits = []
        context.push()
        #print "context->", context
        for child in node.get_children():
            bits.append(self._render_node(context, child))
        context['node'] = node
        context['children'] = mark_safe(','.join(bits))   **#join by ,**
        rendered = self.template_nodes.render(context)
        context.pop()
        return rendered

    def render(self, context):
        queryset = self.queryset_var.resolve(context)
        comment_order = self.order.resolve(context)
        roots = cache_tree_children(queryset, comment_order)
        # print "roots-> ", roots
        bits = [self._render_node(context, node) for node in roots]
        # print bits
        return ','.join(bits)   **#join by ,**
```